# Is it possible to create combo box list items with multiple sections in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, list, uitableview, combobox, sections

Is it possible to create combo box list items with multiple sections in IPhone ? Items List will display same way as we in UITableView.

Comment: Have an "Other" entry in your `UIPickerView`. When this entry is selected, fade out the picker view and replace it with a `UITextField`.

Comment: Actually I want to display title in uitableview with multiple sections that support dropdown as we do in combobox.

Comment: A combobox,as we know it on desktop, does not exist on the iphone. Dropdown lists take too much space so they don't make a lot of sense. Picker views (half screen) and list views (full screen) and segmented controls (max 3 items) are your options.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to use UITableView to display a list for selection?

If you want multiple sections, simply make your numberOfSectionsInTableView method return the number of sections you want. And implement the didSelectionRowAtIndexPath to do whatever you want to do with the selection.

If you mean to say "multiple-selection", you can implement some toggle logic in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, the example below uses the selected property to keep track and use the checkmark acceryType as UI marker. You can also add your own checked property or use the highlighted row as UI indicator.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.selected = YES;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selected = NO;
    }

}
```

I suggest you use a `UIiNavigationController` together with your UITableView. That way you can add an 'OK' or 'Done' button on the nav bar and make the action of that button pop this view and process the all the selected items.